Android Studio/Gradle build doesn't contain assets beginning with a '_' character
In my projects asset folder I have a mix of files and directories. One of these directories begins with a _ and it is not included in the build.
I have narrowed it down to the aaptOptions in my projects build.gradle, however changing the ignored asset pattern as recommended here and here does not produce different results and the directory is still excluded. From what little documentation I have been able to find that option appears to be deprecated. The directory is generated alongside the other files and the name of the directory needs to stay the same. How do you modify this exclusion list using Gradle 7? Thanks so much!
Edit to include build.gradle:
plugins{
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'com.android.library'
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "7.0.2"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

node {
    nodeProjectDir = file("editor")
}

tasks.register('generateStaticBuild', NpxTask) {
    dependsOn npmInstall
    command = 'expo'
    args = ['export', '-p', 'web', '--output-dir', '../src/main/assets/editor']
    inputs.files('package.json', 'package-lock.json', 'app.json', 'app.js', 'babel.config.js')
    inputs.dir("editor/assets")
    inputs.dir(fileTree("editor/node_modules").exclude(".cache"))
    outputs.dir('src/main/assets/editor')
}

